# Make ListView builder behave like Android wrap_content

Tags: flutter

My Column structure is like this:

```
body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TabPanel(), // row with all child text
        new UrlButtonPanel(), // row with button
        new Ad(), //rectangle container
        new LatestNewsController(), //container with swith button
        Expanded(child: new LatestNewsList()), // listview

      ],
  )
```

I want to make whole page scrollable including listView. Right Now only Listview portion is scrollable.

How to make whole page scrollable?

Replacing Column with ListView making layout blank.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829142/5305962 might be useful

Answer (score -2):

Try these changes. It should give you a Scrollable List inside a Scrollable ListView.
edit: in Widget build method add:

```
// Get the screen Height
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
// Get 67% of screen Height
    double containerHeight = screenHeight * 0.67;
// Get the screen Width
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

this will get you screen height and width, then in Container use containerHeight. In this case, I have used 67% of Screen height.

```
body: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      new TabPanel(), // row with all child text
      new UrlButtonPanel(), // row with button
      new Ad(), //rectangle container
      new LatestNewsController(), //container with swith button
      new Container(height: containerHeight, child: yourList()),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: listview height should not be fixed